# Emphasize something with two adverbs

Tags: adverbs, word-order, slang, informal-language

Do you use two adverbs before noun to emphasize something or do you end sentence with three adverbs maybe informal in an informal setting if not formal way? If you do then what is adverb orders?
Can it be ended with adjective?

For example:

> It looks ***right so*** cool.
>
> It's not ***so right*** hot tea as you said.

Defentions:

Right
Chiefly Southern US Considerably; very:

Ex: They have a right nice place.

So
- extremely; very much (used for emphasis).

Ex: "she looked so pretty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Right" is an adjective in standard English. You can use "so" to intensify "right" because "right" is used as an adjective.

- You are so right.
- It looks so right.
- His argument is so right.

Similarly, in Southern American English dialects, "right" is sometimes used to intensify an adjective.

- They have a right nice place.
- He's a right good ballplayer.

However, you cannot use "so" and "right" together where both modify an adjective. I can't imagine a native speaker saying "He looks right so cool."

Your second sentence also has a so/such error. You need to use "such" because you are modifying a noun phrase. "It is not such hot tea as you said." Alternatively, you could say, "The tea is not so hot" or "The tea is not as hot as you said."